# Incompatible Type Assignment

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

The "init_deck" method is returning an error: incompatible types when assigning to type struct Card from type struct * Card
   (*p++ = card_create(rank[k], suits[j]))

I'm not sure what this means or how to go about fixing this. If anyone could explain what this is actually doing at the assembly level and how it corresponds to C it would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

struct Card{
 int value;
 char* suit;
};

struct Card *card_create(int value, char* suit){
 struct Card *theCard = malloc(sizeof(struct Card));
 assert(theCard != NULL);

 theCard->value = value;
 theCard->suit = strdup(suit);

return theCard;
}

void card_destroy(struct Card *theCard){
 assert(theCard != NULL);

 free(theCard->suit);
 free(theCard);
}

void setValue(struct Card *theCard, int value){
 theCard->value = value;
}

int getValue(struct Card *theCard){
 return theCard->value;
}

char* getSuit(struct Card *theCard){
 return theCard->suit;
}

void card_print(struct Card *theCard){
 printf("%i of %s\n", getValue(theCard), getSuit(theCard));
}

void init_deck(struct Card deck[52]){

struct Card *p = deck;
char *suits[] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
int rank[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 74, 81, 75, 65}  //Last 4 numbers are int rep of char: J, Q, K, A
int j = 0, k = 0;
for(; j < 4; j++)
  for(; k < 13; k++)
    (*p++ = card_create(rank[k], suits[j]));
}
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using `(*p)++`, it is possible you increment the pointer instead of the value of p.

Comment: 1) Format that mess properly. 2) C does not allow nested function definitions. Although this is a gcc extension, you should not use it.

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_

Comment: @BLUEPIXY and also memory corruption, there is no memory allocated for *p

Comment: @Garf365 `p`  is `deck`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ooh yes, sorry

Comment: The braces don't match. First fix your syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

`card_create` return pointer, but `*p` isn't pointer. (different type)

(1)

replace

```
*p++ = card_create(rank[k], suits[j])
```

with

```
struct Card *aCard = card_create(rank[k], suits[j]);    
*p++ = *aCard;
card_destroy(aCard);
```

---

(2) card_create non use malloc version

```
struct Card card_create(int value, char* suit){
    struct Card theCard;
    theCard.value = value;
    theCard.suit = strdup(suit);//Since you are using a string literal Strdup it is not required. just theCard.suit = suit;

    return theCard;
}
```

...

```
*p++ = card_create(rank[k], suits[j])
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! This fixed my issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your `deck` should be a a Card** not a Card*.

The result of `card_create` is a `Card*` that you try to put in the `Card` stuct using the pointer `*p`.